# set a key with push so data don't get overridden

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue working with Firebase, I need to have a child called Participants, and a button to add a son that basically is (key= userId, value= username) I already have something like that but the setValue overrides the existed value, I can use push, but with that my key is random, how can I solve that problem?
Here is my code:

```
   myRef.child("Participants").child(id).setValue(username);
            participantAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of just a specific child, call `setValue()` on that specific child node:

```
myRef.child("Participants").child(id).child("name").setValue(username);
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, but i just need 1 child under participants, that child should have a pair key/value where key is my id and value the username

Comment: That's precisely what your original code does: it writes the user name under the child ID. What is the problem?